# Count non-whitespace characters for selection in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

does anyone know of a tool or extension to Visual Studio 2010 to count non-whitespace (e.g. all characters but not spaces, new lines etc.) for current selection in a document?

Nice to have for code golfing :)

I have a command line tool, but an integrated tool would be very nice. Also I would prefer something to evaluate current selection.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just add an external tool to invoke your command line tool?

Comment: Write a macro and bind it to a key.

Comment: I've updated the question to more specifically say that I would prefer something that evaluates current selection. Thus, an external tool to invoke my command line tool is not realy what I am looking for.
However, a macro could be used... but how? :)

Comment: External tools can use the currently selected text `CurText`.

Comment: You should probably read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions before posting anything tagged [code-golf].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got to creating this crude macro below by first recording a temporary macro in Visual Studio and then modifying it to look like the below:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module CountNonWhiteSpaceCharacters
    Sub Count()
        Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection()
        Dim text As String = selection.Text

        text = text.Replace(" ", "")
        text = text.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        text = text.Replace(vbTab, "")

        MsgBox("Count " + text.Length.ToString())
    End Sub    
End Module
```

This can be bound to a keybord shortcut if desired. Otherwise, double clicking it in Macro Explorer will run it.